# SQL Return search set and result

Tags: mysql

How can an sql query to be written so that it will return whether an id is found, for each id searched? Every id searched for in the IN statement should have a row, specifying if a record with that id was found in the table.

**Query guess**

```
Select [id] From table1 Where [id] IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

**Goal Result Set**

```
ID   Found
1    yea
2    naw
3    yea
4    yea
5    naw
```

Comment: So you've tried nothing? You've pretty much figured out the logic, you should give it a go and see what happens.

Comment: You could return all the ids found loop through them and display them in the format you have in your op. Unless you want this purely on db end?

Comment: I've tried my query guess above, but am struggling conceptually with how to return a row for each id in the IN statement as opposed to for each record found.

Answer (score 1):

This version doesn't use `IN` operator, rather it uses `union` in order to get table expression:

```
create table main(id int);
insert into main
select 1 union
select 3 union
select 5


select t.id,
       case when count(m.id) > 0 then 'yep' else 'nope' end as found

from 
(select 1 as id union
 select 2 as id union
 select 3 as id union
 select 4 as id union
 select 5 as id
)t

left join main m on t.id = m.id
group by t.id
```

Output:

```
id  found
1   yep
2   nope
3   yep
4   nope
5   yep
```

Comment: This is essentially running a query for each ID, then concatenating the results?

Comment: Yes this is left join, which will contain all rows from t and corresponding rows from main. If there is no corresponding rows then instead there will be null. And counting will count all rows but it doesn't count nulls.

Comment: Correct answer which illustrates the left join and test necessary for the query, +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that uses a temp table rather than IN operator or several unions.

Create temp table

```
Declare Global Temporary Table session.temp (id decimal(15, 0))
```

Populate temp table

```
Insert Into session.temp (id) values ((1),(2),(3),(4),(5))
```

Query

```
SELECT session.temp.id,
       case when count(table1.id) > 0 Then 'Yep' Else 'Nope' End As Found
FROM session.temp
LEFT JOIN table1
ON session.temp.id = table1.id
GROUP BY temp.id
```